# Why is the address-of operator in C/C++ represented with the "&" symbol?

Tags: history, c, c++, language-design

I've started learning C++, and I know a little bit of C. Something that always struck me as somewhat off was that the address-of operator is represented with the seemingly random ampersand (&) symbol instead of, say, the "at" symbol (@). Is there some kind of history behind this?

Comment: Apparently BCPL [used `@`](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/clive-on-bcpl.html). I thought there might be an answer in Ritchie's ["The Development of the C Language"](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.pdf) but there isn't.

Answer (score 5):

Because B did!

A user on [software engineering.sx](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/273268) contacted Ken Thompson:

> **From: Ken Thompson**
>
> c copied from b so & and * are same there.
> b got * from earlier languages - some assembly,
> bcpl and i think pl/1.
> i think that i used & because the name (ampersand)
> sounds like "address." b was designed to be run with
> a teletype model 33 teletype. (5 bit baud-o code)
> so the use of symbols was restricted.